# Keep android app in foreground unless in in settings

Tags: java, android, cordova

I have an app for a customer (refer to it as "their" app). When "their" app is open they do not want users of the device to use any other apps. 
The only way they want to get round this, is if i create a login page within the app, and from there you can go to the android settings page.  If the android settings are accessed, then the user should be able to go anywhere they want, until "their" app is in the foreground again, then the device should be locked into using just that app.

If this makes any difference, "their" app is a cordova app.  I dont think it will, but thought i would mention it anyway.  Needs to work in android 5.0

Is this possible at all?  What would i need to implement for this?  A service and timer?

**UPDATE**
It is a tablet, so it will never ring.
If the user presses the Home button, nothing should happen as the app should stay in the foreground

Comment: What should happen if they press the home button or if the phone rings?

Comment: Only way I know of getting close to this is with a home/launcher replacement app.

Comment: You would probably need to use Device Administration: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html Also, maybe implement the onStop/HomeButtonPressed/etc and do nothing when they are pressed, maybe block the phone or whatever. Not sure if it would be possible, but definitely not allowed by Google, so in case you try this don't dristribute through Play Store or you might get your account banned.